# intellij: Cannot resolve symbol apache, jsoniter

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a module defined in a scala project in inellij. In module's sbt:

```
"com.jsoniter" % "jsoniter" % "0.9.8",
"org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "2.5.0",
"org.apache.kafka" % "connect-api" % "2.5.0",
```

But I see 'Cannot resolve symbol...' for apache and jsoniter in following imports in some of the files in the module:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{ ConsumerConfig, KafkaConsumer }
import com.jsoniter.JsonIterator
```

From sbt, build is successful.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like IDEA is misinterpreting your Project's structure. Try closing all instances of IDEA, removing the System Directory (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory) and re-importing the Project (double-click the root build.sbt)